# CRA webpack - output separate files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got a CRA app that I have built as a Chrome Extension, however I need to implement https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux

To do so, I need to build my background.js as its own file, as well as the main.js

I've added my path to config/paths.js

```
  backgroundJs: resolveApp('src/background.js'),
```

and my config contains:

```
entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
```

Does anyone know how I can keep my src file built into main.js, but have background.js build to its own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object to `entry`:

```js
module.exports = {
   /* ... */
   entry: {
      main: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
      background: resolveApp('src/background.js'),
   }
   /* ... */
}
```

Check the document: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/.

Comment: Oh well that was much more straight forward that I thought it'd be.  Thanks!